# Using a response from server to output in html

Tags: python, html, json

I am totally new to HTML and I would like to know how tu use json returns from a server to output in an html file.

More specifically, I have a python script that when executed gives me as a response a json object. I would like to print it out on a html file through my browser. How can I do this?

Do I write my html to somehow launch my script and capture the object?

Answer (score 1):

For example you can go through this code where in a sweetalert you can show your response from server
**Component:**

```
    subscription(subscriptionEmail: Object) {
    this.contactusService.newsLetterData(subscriptionEmail).subscribe(res => {
      console.log(res);
      swal({
        title: res['Message'],
        type: 'success'
      });
      this.router.navigate(['home']);

    });
  }
```

**Service:**

```
     newsLetterData(  newsLetter: {}): Observable<boolean> {

    return this.http.post<any>(AUTHURL + '/PageSlammer/newsLetter',  { newsLetter})
      .pipe(
        map(result => {

          //  localStorage.setItem('loggdIn', 'true');
          return result;
        }),
      );
  }
```